# Get id from hash in array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
g_list = [
  {:groups => [{:id => 5}]},
  {:groups => [{:id => 6}]}
]
```

I need to get an array of `:id` values from the structure. I want to get `[5, 6]`.

How can I iterate through an array of hashes, and `dig` the items inside?

I tried to use `map` and `dig`:

```
g_list.map{|g| g.dig(:groups, :id)}
```

but I receive an error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. I also tried to handle it with `each` loop for single example of groups:

```
g_list.each do |g|
   groups = g.dig(:groups)
   puts groups[:id]
end
```

but I still get the same error. I finally wrote this:

```
arr = g_list.map {|g| g.dig(:groups).map{|i| i[:id]}}.flatten
```

and it returns what I expected, but I wonder whether I can write this in a better way.

Comment: What does `g.dig(:groups)` return you? It's not a hash, is it?

Comment: `g_list.each { |g|  puts g.dig(:groups) }`  prints  {:id=>5}
{:id=>6}, but when a = g_list.each { |g|  g.dig(:groups) } is first, whole array with hashes -> `[{:groups=>[{:id=>5}]}, {:groups=>[{:id=>6}]}]`

Comment: `g_list` will not work with your example with `each`. Please, fix either `g_list` or that example.

Comment: @eudaimonia: for first one, use `p`, not `puts`. For second, use `map`, not `each`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I added last working example, I wonder can I write this better way?

Comment: Does `:groups` alwasy point to array with one element?

Comment: In view of the comments below there appears to be confusion about your question, confusion that is summed up by @yzalavin's question above, which for some reason you have chosen not to answer. Considering that the arrays in your example each contain a single hash, and that you have not stated that those arrays could contain more than one hash, I think you must answer yzalavin's question, "yes"; otherwise you would be changing your question, rendering at least sawa's answer incorrect. If you wish to allow the arrays to contain more than one hash, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following returns a list with all group ids, even if an element contains more than one group.

```
g_list = [
  {:groups => [{:id => 5}]},
  {:groups => [{:id => 6}]}
]

arr = g_list.flat_map { |g| g[:groups] }.map { |i| i[:id] }
arr #=> [5, 6]

g_list = [
  {:groups => [{:id => 5}]},
  {:groups => [{:id => 6}, {:id => 7}]}
]

arr = g_list.flat_map { |g| g[:groups] }.map { |i| i[:id] }
arr #=> [5, 6, 7]
```

Assuming all elements have a `:groups` key.

Answer (score 3):

Array indices can be passed as part of the arguments to your `dig` call. You want index `0` to extract the single element from the array.

```
g_list.map{|g| g.dig(:groups, 0, :id)}
# => [5, 6]
```

Comment: This one is much cleaner indeed! (compared to all the flattens)

Comment: But what if an item has more than one group? You only return the first one.

Comment: @JohanWentholt That is a different question.

Comment: It's not, look in the question, @eudaimonia maps over all groups and gets all the ids.

Comment: @JohanWentholt That is because the OP couldn't come up with anything else that works. Look in the question, the OP initially wanted something like `g_list.map{|g| g.dig(:groups, :id)}`. The OP is also explicitly asking how to do this with `dig`.

Comment: I'm afraid that this returns only first id, but there is array, I'm not sure about that